# How to add new line break in content-type : text/plain document generated by php?

Tags: php

I want to add a link break in a text file. How do I do that?

My code is as follows.

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
?>
Line 1
Line 2
Line 2
```

I have tried following.

```
1. echo 'Line'."\n\r"
2. echo nl2br('Line'."\n\r")
3. echo 'Line' . PHP_EOL
4. echo 'Line' . "<br/>"
```

Nothing is working.

Comment: use \n for new line

Comment: I believe PHP_EOL  is better

Comment: When I do "\n" , then I get <br> in browser as output. This is what I tried =>echo nl2br("User-agent: *\r\n"); and I get o/p => User-agent:<br>

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

`\n` for new line when content-type is `text/plain`

`<br>` for new line when content-type is `text/html`

Comment: I researched and found that we need to call nl2br('\r\n') in order to make '/n' working. How do I use the '\n' to output text in new line?

Comment: yes @muhammad, thats absolutely correct. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad it helped.